# Undefined columns selected r

Tags: r, subset

sorry to annoy you with such a basic problem but I am using data from the European Social Survey and I cannot subset the data for France::

```
data <- read.dta("ESS1.dta")
head(data)

france <- data[,data$cntry=="FR"]

# Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , data$cntry == "FR"):  undefinedcolumns selected
```

Thank you

Comment: `subset(data, data$cntry == "FR")` should do it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I was trying to subset on the columns instead of the rows